# Get information about route from google map

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web-crawler, phantomjs

I lost much time for find a solution but still nothing. I want get information from google maps and store screen of this map on image.

I try to combine pjscrape and html2canvas to render this map to image. My goal is to save screen map to image and get coordinates of road.

Maybe I chose bad approach to do this, maybe I try to reinvent wheel and it's ready module to this?

For example I want get this information from map:

http://www.mapmyride.com/fr/paris-ile-de-france/5-52km-road-cycling-on-09-09-13-route-286292763

But, I don't want use description on this site - need information only from map.

I try to load html2canvas in pjs:

```
require('./html2canvas');
pjs.config({ 
    // options: 'stdout', 'file' (set in config.logFile) or 'none'
    log: 'stdout',
    // options: 'json' or 'csv'
    format: 'json',
    // options: 'stdout' or 'file' (set in config.outFile)
    writer: 'file',
    outFile: 'scrape_output.json'
});
pjs.addSuite({
    // single URL or array
    url: '',
        scraper: function() {
        //html2canvas can't use it because it's undefined in this scope
        return '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors with your code, what is happening when you run your code?

Comment: ReferenceError html2canvas is not defined. I run it by command pyphantomjs /path/to/pjscrape.js my_config.js